# Take input from a form and format it as salutation, initials and surname

Tags: vba, forms, ms-word, letter

Hi I have created a form in Microsoft Word VBA and it has a text field called fCustFullName. The user would input a name in the following format (all caps): `FIRST MIDDLE MIDDLE MIDDLE LAST` (There could be multiple middle names, or none at all).

I've looked on Google and other Stackexchange questions but can't figure out how to convert that in to initials and a surname.

> E.g. Input: JOHN APPLE BANANA ORANGE SMITH
>
> .Bookmarks("addressline1").Range.Text = J A B O Smith

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a moment to read the site guidelines on asking effective questions in the [help]. This isn't a free coding service or tutorial site - you're expected to show some effort and ask specifically targeted questions. That's why the answer you've gotten is very brief - it matches the information you gave. Do you know how to work with an ARRAY (the result of a Split function)? Have you done any research on that?

Answer (score 0):

Look into using:

```
 Split(LString, " ")
```

method and also manipulating the string like an array.

Comment: I did see this recommendation in other questions but I'm not sure how to access the ouput of 'Split'. In my example of .Bookmarks("addressline1").Range.Text = ? What would I put here to call the first character of each Split output?

Comment: you can use the split function again

Comment: Split("string", delimiter, limit), the limit acts as the number of times to delimit, so if you set that to 1 and the delimeter to "" then it should take the first

Comment: I'm sorry I still don't understand how this function works. I've read the MSDN article on Split but I still don't get it. Can you please show example code that would take FRED ALBERT RODNEY FLINSTONE and convert it to F A R Flinstone?

Comment: What do you propose to do about multi-word surnames (e.g. St James, Van der Linden)?

Comment: @macropod well that throws a spanner in the works. Okay maybe I need two input boxes so surnames are separate. Thanks for pointing this out

Comment: Glad to be of help. You might also want to give some thought to how you treat given names such as Kerry-Anne. Should such a name be abbreviated to K, KA, or K-A, for example.